# Issue installing IE11

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, wsus, internet-explorer-11

I've been using WSUS to roll out IE11, there's a few stranglers that IE11 will not install and I've started looking into. Here's what I've done.

1. Confirmed [all prerequisite](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2847882) updates have been done.
2. I'm using the x64 bit package of ie11 and only using x64 servers and workstations.
3. I've ran `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`, which has come back clean.
4. Ran [KB947821](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821)
5. Ran `sfc /scannow` which has also come back clean.

Digging up the `IE11_main.log` install file, I've found the following:

```
00:37.188: INFO:    The neutral pack was successfully downloaded from the internet. Installation will continue using the downloaded package.
00:37.188: INFO:    Waiting for 0 language pack downloads.
00:37.188: INFO:    Language pack downloads completed. (exit code = 0xffffffff (4294967295)).
00:37.282: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiStart(0), lParam=0x00742790 returned 0x00000000.
00:41.922: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiScan(1), lParam=0x00000001 returned 0x00000000.
00:41.922: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiStartInstall(4), lParam=0x00000001 returned 0x00000014.
00:41.922: INFO:    Installing with the downloaded package. C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1B79D.tmp\IE11-neutral.Downloaded.cab
00:42.032: INFO:    Launched package installation: C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1B79D.tmp\IE11-neutral.Downloaded.cab /quiet /norestart
01:03.750: INFO:    Process exit code 0x00003701 (14081) [The referenced assembly could not be found. ]
01:03.766: ERROR:   Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x00003701 (14081)).
```

6. I've confirmed that the path `C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1B79D.tmp\` exists and that `IE11-neutral.Downloaded.cab` is there. Before it removes the folder

The best I can guess is that it's having issues using dism out of the c:\windows\sysnative folder. I've tested accessing c:\windows\sysnative through x86 powershell.

I've checked other servers and confirmed that the install is using `C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1B79D.tmp\IE11-neutral.Downloaded.cab /quiet /norestart` as well.

Googling doesn't seem to provide too much information about what issue I'm having, including looking up the error code `Process exit code 0x00003701 (14081)`. Any assistance understanding why IE11 won't install would be greatly appreciated.